# HTML5 and filesystem management

Tags: html, filesystems

I have a directory with files and I want to search into that directory for some files types.
Is it possible to do that with the new file-system API?

Comment: I think you can only do this with a server side language. Or if you got the file list in an javascript array you can search for it.

Answer (score 0):

No, You are restricted to a sand-boxed directory client side directory within the AppData for your web-browswer.

With Chrome and windows 7 for example:

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\{browswer-user}\Default\File System\
```

Also, you can only access files/directories you've generated and populated via API calls.